# Nesting web applications in IIS and web.config issue

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

### Current installation

I have two web applications app_A and app_B (same app with app_A but for test purposes) under IIS default website. A domain www.mydomain.com that points to the server needs to access app_A. That can be done by changing the physical path from \inetpub\wwwroot\ to \inetpub\wwwroot\app_A.
The second application should be access under www.mydomain.com/app_B/

### Problem

When accessing www.mydomain.com/app_B/ because it's now a sub-directory of app_A it sees the web.config from app_A and I got error like "duplicate entries in web.config" when accessing the www.mydomain.com/app_B/ application. I can eliminate the errors by using the  tag to remove first and declare again the entries in app_B web.config.

### Questions

- Is there any other way to make the installation in order app_A would be access from www.mydomain.com/ and app_B from www.mydomain.com/app_B without messing the web.config files as described above?
- For the current installation, is there a way to set something on IIS in order for app_B not to see at all web.config from app_A because is a subdirectory?
- For the current installation, do you see any real problems (possibly on security) by using  the remove tag for the app_B application?
- For the current installation I observer a strange behaviour. If I login to app_A and app_B and logout from app_A it also logout from app_B (not always). I am using Active Directory for authentication. Do I need to change something in app_B's web.config in order to say that it's totally different application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question and you might have found out the solution. I am replying in case you need an answer.

There are two ways to avoid merging of parent’s config file and child’s config file.  Either you can add 
inheritInChildApplications="false" Tag in the parent’s config file. For example:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <connectionStrings>
   </connectionStrings>
</location>
```

Or

you can add "Remove" tag or "Clear" in child’s config file to clear the parent’s settings.

Also, I don’t see any security threats by clearing parents settings.

By any chance are you using same cookie name in authentication for parent and child applications? If this is the case, once you login to child application, the cookie generated by the parent application will be overridden. Try specifying name of the cookie for at least one of the application.

Comment: Thank you for answering an old question. I used the clear parent's settings as a solution.